# Wakelock is not releasing even after the app is force closed

Tags: android, android-service, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I am using service class along with wakelock functionality to make the application work in the background even if the screen is off or sleep. But even if i force close the application the wakelock is not releasing and the app is working in the background. I have attached the service class code below.

**Snippet**

```
     @Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock= mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();

    wakeLock.release();
}
```

I am acquiring the wakelock in the onCreate method of the service class and releasing it in the onDestroy method of the same class. How to overcome this issue. I am new to services and wakelocks. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

MainActivity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


    Intent serviceIntent  = new Intent(context , MyLocationService.class);
    context.startService(serviceIntent  );



    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    } else {
        Log.d("onCreate", "Google Play Services available.");
    }
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Location service

```
public class MyLocationService extends IntentService {
private static final String TAG = "MyLocationService";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 3000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0f;
Context context = this;
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
public int e=0;

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};

/**
 * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
 *
 * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
 */
public MyLocationService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    wakeLock.release();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    initializeLocationManager();
    PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock= mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[1]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
   // wakeLock.release();
    super.onDestroy();


    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}

// create LocationListener class to get location updates
private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
{
    Location mLastLocation;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    LatLng latLngcurrent;


    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Store.latu=latitude;
        Store.longu=longitude;
        latLngcurrent = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(context,"Location " + String.valueOf(e), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e++;
        Toast.makeText(MyLocationService.this,Store.latu+" "+Store.longu, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: move  wakeLock.release(); before  super.onDestroy();

Comment: sorry for the late response. I tried it before onDestroy(); but still no change. I have closed the application even from background but still its updating the values. @DivyeshPatel

Comment: r u using Intent service?

Comment: yes exactly. from my main activity's Oncreate i am calling the intent @DivyeshPatel

Comment: Is oncreate repeatedly call in intent service? or you start service from any other location?

Comment: if you are using intent service then override onHandleIntent() method and do work there not in Oncreate. and move wakelog.release() code after your work done.

Comment: I have added the Oncreate code in question. can you pls explain me what should i do now? @DivyeshPatel

Comment: use this method:  @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("WAKElog","stopping");
        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "TRYNOTIFY");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        fetchingDATA(city);
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143083/discussion-between-rakesh-polo-and-divyesh-patel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
I have finally found the solution for this. its very simple. In your manifest while using the tag  add this line too.

**Snippet:**

```
 <service android:name=".MyLocationService"
 android:stopWithTask="true"></service>
```

stopWithTask will stop the service when we force close the application and the WakeLock will also stop.

[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ServiceInfo.html) is the documentation. After adding this my application works fine.